# Getting ERROR:" An ARRAY index is out of bounds in statement"

Tags: arrays, sas, survival-analysis

I'm getting the: "ERROR: An ARRAY index is out of bounds in statement" in the log while trying to arrays in a phreg command. I'm trying to do survival analysis using SAS.

````
ERROR: An ARRAY index is out of bounds in statement number 1 at line 2649 column 1.
      The statement was:
   1     (2649:1)   eud = eud_[(tid=.) + 1]
ERROR: An ARRAY index is out of bounds in statement number 2 at line 2652 column 1.
      The statement was:
   1     (2652:1)   ungdom = ungdom_[(tid=.) + 1]
ERROR: An ARRAY index is out of bounds in statement number 3 at line 2655 column 1.
      The statement was:
   1     (2655:1)   kvu = kvu_[(tid=.) + 1]
ERROR: An ARRAY index is out of bounds in statement number 4 at line 2658 column 1.
      The statement was:
   1     (2658:1)   mvu = mvu_[(tid=.) + 1]
ERROR: An ARRAY index is out of bounds in statement number 5 at line 2661 column 1.
      The statement was:
   1     (2661:1)   lvu = lvu_[(tid=.) + 1]
ERROR: An ARRAY index is out of bounds in statement number 1 at line 2649 column 1.
      The statement was:
   1     (2649:1)   eud = eud_[(tid=.) + 1]
ERROR: An ARRAY index is out of bounds in statement number 2 at line 2652 column 1.
      The statement was:
   1     (2652:1)   ungdom = ungdom_[(tid=.) + 1]
ERROR: An ARRAY index is out of bounds in statement number 3 at line 2655 column 1.
      The statement was:
   1     (2655:1)   kvu = kvu_[(tid=.) + 1]
ERROR: An ARRAY index is out of bounds in statement number 4 at line 2658 column 1.
      The statement was:
   1     (2658:1)   mvu = mvu_[(tid=.) + 1]
ERROR: An ARRAY index is out of bounds in statement number 5 at line 2661 column 1.
      The statement was:
   1     (2661:1)   lvu = lvu_[(tid=.) + 1]  ```
````

This is the editor input for creating the cats, which is obv. done for each of the new cats:

```
    array ungdomone(*)ungdom1-ungdom26;                                                                  
     do i=1 to 26;                                                                                
        if pstart=1 then ungdomone[i]=.;                                                                                                                           
        if tid+1=i then ungdomone[i]=ungdom;                                                     
        if tid=. then ungdomone[i]=.;                                                              
    end;                                                                                          

    drop i;
```

This is the phreg we are trying to use:

```
proc phreg data=biblio.worklife;
model tid*censor(1,2,3,4) = sex eud ungdom kvu mvu lvu/* Baseline grundskole */ /ties=efron;

array eud_(*) eud1-eud26;
eud=eud_[tid+1];

array ungdom_(*) ungdom1-ungdom26;
ungdom=ungdom_[tid+1];

array kvu_(*) kvu1-kvu26;
kvu=kvu_[tid+1];

array mvu_(*) mvu1-mvu26;
mvu=mvu_[tid+1];

array lvu_(*) lvu1-lvu26;
lvu=lvu_[tid+1];

run;
```

If I can provide anymore useful info, let me know!
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please add your program language in tag list

Comment: I've added the SAS tag, I hope that was the answer to your question?

Comment: Why array ungdomone(\*)ungdom1-ungdom26; instead of array ungdomone[\*] ungdom1-ungdom26;

Comment: See this http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/97529_Using_Arrays_in_SAS_Programming.pdf for manage arrays

Comment: Im afraid this didn't fix the problem and [ ] are interchangeable with ( ) as we replicated the exact same error. Will have a look at the manual you linked, thank you!

Comment: The log message shows that `tid` is missing, which causes `tid + 1` to be missing, which is not a valid array index. Check your input data for missing values in `tid`.

Comment: @Chris That seems to be the exact answer to my problem! What I did was add `tid ne .` when i made the data cut and that fixed the "tid"-issue in arrays ("tid"=time). Thank you very much for the help!